# Trying to load data that is being passed by using a store

Tags: javascript, extjs, playframework, store, datastore

I am trying to get data that is being passed and load it into various textfields. Right now, I have a .html file which contains this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var res = {"address":"","city":"","state":"","zip":""};
</script>
```

Then, I have a .js file which contains my entire layout with all the textfields, etc. and my entire store. This is what I have so far as my store trying to load the data, but I am not sure what the correct method is to try and get the data from the html file and display it on my js file.

```
var newStore= new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
        fields: ['address', 'city', 'state', 'zip'],
        loadData: (res),
        idIndex: 0 
    });
```

Could someone please help me as I am a bit lost on what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Try ArrayStore Like this.

```
var newStore= new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
    fields: ['address', 'city', 'state', 'zip']
     });
newStore.add(res);
newStore.commitChanges()
```

This should work.